# Como reutilizar código de uma activity em outra?

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou criando uma aplicação no android studio em que tenho um menu, estou utilizando esse menu em diversas activitys usando "include" , então em cada activity eu preciso reescrever as funções dos botões do menu, como eu poderia fazer um método separado que funcionasse em todas as activitys?

Comment: Crie uma primeira activity com o código que se repete. Quando quiser que uma nova activity use esse código faça ela herdar da primeira.

Comment: como eu posso fazer isso? usando extends?

Comment: Sim, usando `extends`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cria uma classe separada e instancia ela passando this
Exemplo
MainActivity.class - contém os métodos onCreate e cia
MeuMenu.class - contém o método criaMenu

No método onCreate da MainActivity voce chama o MeuMenu meuMenu = new MeuMenu(this); e depois meuMenu.criaMenu();
Na classe MeuMenu, você recebe o parâmetro this, que vai ser do tipo da activity...que provavelmente é Activity ou AppCompatActivity...

Para conseguir acessar os métodos da MainActivity na MeuMenu, como por exemplo findViewById, você precisará chamar esse parâmetro que recebeu (do tipo Activity ou AppCompatActivity)...exemplo parametro.findViewById(R.id.menu);

Aí, toda activity que precisa desse menu é só chamar MeuMenu meuMenu = new MeuMenu(this); e depois meuMenu.criaMenu(); para criar um menu... É claro que esse menu deve estar no xml também.

Exemplo:

MainActivity.class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MeuMenu meuMenu = new MeuMenu(this);
        meuMenu.criaMenu(R.id.btn); // id do xml
    }
```

MeuMenu.class

```
Activity activity;
Button button;

public MeuMenu(Activity activity){
   this.activity = activity;
}

public void criaMenu(int id){
    button = (Button) activity.findViewByid(id);
    button.setOnClickListener...
}
```

Aliás, você pode usar esse padrão para organizar melhor o código, removendo todos os botões e eventos das activities e passando para uma classe separada...

Comment: Perfeito Anderson, obrigado!